# Use LINQ instead of foreach

Tags: performance, linq

I have a C# list with data for customers. I need a BranchCode field for each customer, from another data source, which I look up and  store in a second list. The unique key for a customer is the customer abbreviation, which is in each list. How do I look up each customer in the second list, find its `BranchCode`, and update (or create a new list) the first list with it, using LINQ?

I can do it this way:

```
foreach (var item in oracleData)
{
    var oracleDataWithBranchCodeCustomer = 
        inOrderToGetBranchCodeInAReallyStupidWay.Find(customer => customer.CustomerAbbreviation == item.CustomerAbbreviation);

    if (oracleDataWithBranchCode != null)
       item.BranchCode = oracleDataWithBranchCodeCustomer.BranchCode;
}
```

But every attempt to do it in LINQ fails. How do I do it? Also, which is faster in general, LINQ or foreach?

Comment: What is the Linq method that fails? Using a join would be more efficient than the approach you have here.

Comment: Show us your attempts with LINQ please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But every attempt to do it in LINQ fails. How do I do it?

You shouldn't. Linq is for *querying*, not *updating*. Since your loop has side effects, a `foreach` is perfectly fine.

One thing you *could* do is do a `join` instead of looking up each item in the second list:

```
    foreach (var pairs in 
                (from item in oracleData 
                 join customer in inOrderToGetBranchCodeInAReallyStupidWay
                 on item.CustomerAbbreviation equals customer.CustomerAbbreviation
                 select new {item, customer.BranchCode} ))
    {
           pairs.item.BranchCode = pairs.BranchCode;
    }
```

you can decide which makes more sense to a reader. You could also improve performance in other ways, such as by creating a `Dictionary` so that lookups by branch code are O(`) in your customer list.

> Also, which is faster in general, LINQ or foreach?

For *equivalent* loops, Linq will have some overhead due to the creation of iterators, but whether or not that overhead is *significant* depends on what the loop is doing. For example, adding 2 ms of iteartor time to a loop that takes 500 ms to process each item is not significant. On the other hand, I've seen Linq queries that operate on a string as a collection of characters that are orders of magnitude slower than native indexer access. For most everything else, Linq will be insignificantly slower.  You can also write an inefficient `foreach` loop that is much slower than a functionally equivalent Linq query (e.g. a loop that doesn't break when it finds the one match it's expecting vs. a `First` query that does)

Remember that Linq is about productive *code writing*, not about code performance.

Comment: "Linq will have some overhead due to the creation of iterators, but whether or not that overhead is significant depends on what the loop is doing" - this statement is a bit misleading. LINQ does have a minimal amount of overhead when creating iterators, but that overhead doesn't change based on what the loop is doing. Your statement makes it sound like the content of the loop changes the actual duration of time that the iterator takes to run. It's just a relative difference and the iterator time is likely to be insignificant.